# targeting different div styles with target method

Tags: html, css

Hello I am using the target method to manipulate different div styles, for the first "link_one" everything is working, while I have only one link, the question is how to make it work for "link_two" ? So link_two will do the second part of the css ? What is more important here is that each link is maniluplating 2 different classes in which link one and two one of the class is the same.

```
<a href="#sections">link_one</a>

<div id="sections">
<div id="link_one">info</div>
<div id="link_two">info</div>
</div>

/* link one code */ 
    #sections:target #link_one{
        height:90px;
        background:#333;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }

    #sections:target .rslides {
        height:0px;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }

/* link two code */ 
  #sections:target #link_two{
        height:90px;
        background:#333;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }

    #sections:target .rslides {
        height:0px;
        transition:all 1s ease;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand how the [:target selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_:target_selector) works? It's based on the URL that's in the browser's address bar.

Comment: yes I am sure, instead of making different container div layers for each link I am searching for some more inteligent variation on this problem.

Comment: a fiddle would help communicate what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to apply the target selector would be:

for this HTML

```
<a href="#sections1">link_one</a>
<br>
<a href="#sections2">link_two</a>

<div id="sections1"></div>
<div id="sections2"></div>
<div id="link_one" class="link">info</div>
<div id="link_two" class="link">info</div>
```

Set this CSS

```
 .link {
    height: 20px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

#sections1:target ~ #link_one{
    height:90px;
    background:#333;
}

#sections2:target ~ #link_two{
    height:90px;
    background:#333;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCZr8/)